# Non-linear least squares and the distribution of an estimator

Tags: nonlinear-regression, normality-assumption, asymptotics, estimators

I have been trying to find the asymptotic normality of the non-linear least squares estimator. If I start with $0=X_t(\beta)'(y_t-x_t(\beta))$. I know that I have to perform Taylor expansion around the true parameter $β_0$. I can do that for the $x(b)$ (the one in the brackets). Then I will substitute $y=Xβ_0 + u$ and then the goal is to find an expression such as $n^{1/2}(\beta-\beta_0)$. This expression will be equal to something that I can apply the CLT. What troubles me is the first $X(b)'$ (the one outside the brackets).

Should I perform Taylor expansion for this term as well?

Thanks in advance. Any help will be highly appreciated as I have been struggling with this problem for a while.

Comment: What is the "non-linear least squares estimator"? Are you thinking of using ordinary least squares to estimate a nonlinear regression model? Unless I'm mistaken, it isn't done that way.

Comment: Well the ordinary least squares  can be used to estimate non linear function in the explanatory variables. However, if the parameters are not linear linear (for example 1/b) we cannot use ordinary least squares. In such case we minimize the SSR from the nonlinear regression function and try to obtain an estimate using Newton's method or Gaus/Newton's method.

Comment: Never mind. I found the solution

Comment: You can provide an answer to your own question & accept it.  That will be helpful for future searchers who want to know this.